# Is there a way a browser can directly talk to android application?

Tags: android, google-chrome

It seems there is an initiative from Google to directly send the map directions from Chrome to Android device. I was wondering is there a way browser can communicate with directly an  Android application, where the Android device is connected to the system by Cable. This will be helpful in some scenarios where the user does not have access to Wifi, and he wants to download the data to the mobile phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the [Android Intent invocation](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/intents) that is available in the Android browser and demonstrated in [here](http://mobile-html.appspot.com/#35).

The problem that you will face is that not every app supports the ability to be opened from the Web Browser.  This also relies on the fact that you are on the same machine and doesn't solve your "cabled" issue.  You will also have to know how to exactly integrate with these Android apps, and that is not something that they often expose.

Answer (score 0):

For a few reasons there is often no direct access to local files/devices from inside a browser. When cabled, you can `forward` a tcp port of the android system to local system, using Android Debugging Bridge(adb).

So you can send some commands/data to the device by setting up an application in android who listens to particular tcp port, and forward the port to local system. Then all access to the local port is forwarded to this application. Then with such techniques like `jsonp`, your browser can communicate with your device.